# Define Access to External Domains in Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I have a phonegapp application, connected to an API hosted on heroku. I'm using Codio, and Canary as my emulator. As I load the google chrome dev tools to view my app, it connects than as I look in the Network tab; it gives me these 3 errors;

```
(index):98 GET http://pinball-spring.codio.io:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://venuetoronto.herokuapp.com/api/v1/neighbourhoods. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://pinball-spring.codio.io:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://venuetoronto.herokuapp.com/api/v1/search/meta. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://pinball-spring.codio.io:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I've looked through the phonegap/apache/cordova docs, and it says for whitelisting a domain (which is what I think I'm trying to do); to go in to the config.xml file and it shows this;

```
<!--
  Define access to external domains.

  <access />            - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
  <access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.

  Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:
-->

<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->

<!--
  <access origin="http://phonegap.com" /> - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
  <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />  - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/  
  <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
-->
```

[image: Image of the emulator screen]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
<access origin="http://pinball-spring.codio.io" />
```

or

```
<access origin="http://venuetoronto.herokuapp.com" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also in this scenario for about four days until i finally find a fix.
I know you would have been seeing it at different places to edit your config.xml file with:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

But for whatever reason, that didn't work for me until i change the above to:

```
<access origin=".*" />
```

And everything started working normally;
-ajax was able to access external hosts
-links to external web pages are also opening 
Finally, here is the config file that worked for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "com.sucep.app"
    versionCode = "10" 
    version     = "1.0.0" >


<name>App Name</name>
<description>
    My description 
</description>

<author href="http://tormuto.com" email="support@tormuto.com">
    Tormuto
</author>

<access origin="*" />
<access origin=".*" /> 
<icon src="icon.png" />

<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
    <uses-permission name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</gap:config-file>

<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
    <uses-permission name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</gap:config-file>  

<gap:plugin name="com.simplec.plugins.network" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.5.2" />
</widget>
```